# Cannot redeclare App\funtion_name()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a function

```
function getImg($img,$str,$input){
    // dd($img);

    $img_path = public_path().'/images/photos/devices/'.$img.'.jpg';
    if(file_exists($img_path)){
        if(strpos($input,$str)){
            return $img;
        }else{
            return 'no-img';
        }
    }else{
        return 'no-img';
    }
}
```

---

Then, I call it like this

```
getImg('phone','phone',$input);
```

Why do I keep getting this error ?

> Cannot redeclare App\getImg()

---

## The whole function

```
public static function img($input){

    $img_path = public_path().'/images/photos/devices/';
    $images = scandir($img_path, 1);

    $devices = [];
    foreach($images as $i=>$image){
        if($image != '.' && $image != '..' && $image != '.DS_Store'){
            $name  = str_replace('.jpg', '', $image);
            $devices[$i]['name'] = $name;
        }
    }


    // dd($devices);
    // dd($input);


    foreach ($devices as $i=>$device) {

        $matches = array_filter($devices, function($device) use ($input) {
          return strpos($input, $device['name']) !== FALSE;
        });

        if(count($matches) > 0){

            foreach ($matches as $match) {

                $input = $match['name'];

                $img_path = public_path().'/images/photos/devices/'.$input.'.jpg';
                if(file_exists($img_path)){
                    return $input;
                }else{
                    return 'no-img';
                }

            }
        }else{

            // dd($input);

            function getImg($img,$str,$input){
                // dd($img);

                $img_path = public_path().'/images/photos/devices/'.$img.'.jpg';
                if(file_exists($img_path)){
                    if(strpos($input,$str)){
                        return $img;
                    }else{
                        return 'no-img';
                    }
                }else{
                    return 'no-img';
                }
            }

            getImg('phone','phone',$input);
            getImg('ipad','ipad',$input);
            getImg('iphone','iphone',$input);
            // getImg('imac','imac');

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should be declared outside the foreach loop like so

```
        function getImg($img,$str,$input){
            // dd($img);

            $img_path = public_path().'/images/photos/devices/'.$img.'.jpg';
            if(file_exists($img_path)){
                if(strpos($input,$str)){
                    return $img;
                }else{
                    return 'no-img';
                }
            }else{
                return 'no-img';
            }
        }

        foreach ($devices as $i=>$device) {
        ..........
        }
```

Comment: Ahh ok. I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as solved if it helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP a function is always in the global scope, this is different from JavaScript, where functions in functions are common.

So when you call your function `img` a second time it will try to redeclare the function `getImg`.

You should define your function outside of the first one, or wrap it in :

```
if ( ! function_exists('getImg')) {
...declare function
}
```

From the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> All functions and classes in PHP have the global scope - they can be
>   called outside a function even if they were defined inside and vice
>   versa.